# Trying to submit app binary- no provisioning profiles found for app?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am working in Xcode 6 beta 5 (Swift) and am trying to upload my binary (my code, my app, whatever else it may be referred to as) to iTunes Connect in order to put my app on the app store.

The status of my app in iTunes Connect is Waiting for Upload. I have tried to submit my app using Application Loader. That did not work (I zipped the whole folder and when selected, I got an error that there was no .app bundle) so I archived my app and have been trying to submit through the organizer. Whenever I do this, I get the message that there are "no provisioning profiles found" for my app when I have made 100% sure that there are. I have created multiple provisioning profiles in the member center. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: According to my knowledge, we cannot submit apps by a Beta Version. Are you sure you can submit apps ion Beta?

Comment: I set my deployment target to 7.1 so I don't see why there should be a problem. Do you know exactly how to load in an app binary using Application Loader by any chance?

Comment: Did you test you app with an iPhone / iPad before? So did that work or did it say the same?

Comment: That works fine. Everything's great. It isn't a problem with the code.